# Want to format a second to dd:hh:mm:ss to remove the zero values for readability in Excel 2016

Tags: excel-2016

I have the solution to convert seconds to a correct value of xx Days yy Hours zz Minutes aa Seconds and I want to know a way to have the output drop the values and labels if the value is 00.

Have been looking through several sites and found all the great ways to manipulate the seconds to change the format but I suspect I will need a function to get the desired output.

Here is my code to convert seconds to correct format:

```
=TEXT(G2/(24*60*60),"dd \D\a\y\s hh \H\o\u\r\s mm \M\i\n\u\t\e\s ss \S\e\c\o\n\d\s")
```

60 (as my source seconds) comes across in the output as 00 Days 00 Hours 01 Minutes 00 Seconds.  I want it to say 01 Minutes with the other values removed. 12600 (as my source seconds) comes across in the output as 00 Days 03 Hours 30 Minutes 00 Seconds.  I want it to say 03 Hours 30 Minutes with the other values removed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use =Concatenate(If(......)) to achieve this. 
Just for the demonstration, I added 4 more columns, each for day, hour, minute and second and then concatenated them into one.
My data is at cell C2. And formulae are below :

```
Cell H2 : =TEXT(C$2/(24*60*60),"dd")
Cell I2 : =TEXT(C$2/(24*60*60),"hh")
Cell J2 : =TEXT(C$2/(24*60*60),"mm")
Cell K2 : =TEXT(C$2/(24*60*60),"ss")
```

The above four will just extract the actual number of day/hour/minute/second. And the following four will add suffix to it based on whether the value is zero or non-zero.

```
Cell L2 : =CONCATENATE(IF(H2<>"00",CONCATENATE(H2," days"),""))
Cell M2 : =CONCATENATE(IF(I2<>"00",CONCATENATE(I2," hours"),""))
...
...
```

Finally, just concatenate L2 through O2 to achieve desired result.

```
=CONCATENATE(L2," ", M2," ",N2," ",O2)
```

You might want to download the demo implementation from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QvknZq4PPy4xuX-xp3xViEGBfJaSotlW/view?usp=sharing).